# display first two pargraphs from a content in php

Tags: php, drupal

I want to display first two paragraphs from a content in a particular page. i know it could be done on the basis of number of characters. Is there any possible way to display it based on the paragraphs. The content is purely text.

Comment: Would be nice if you accept an answer!

Answer (score 3):

explode function witth "\n" as separator :

```
$arrTxt = explode("\n", $string);
```

Example:

```
$string = "Line 1....\nline 2\nAnother line";
$arrTxt = explode("\n", $string);
var_dump($arr);
```

Result:

0 => string 'Line 1....'
  1 => string 'line 2'
  2 => string 'Another line'

This may return empty if there is a double return, so it is probably better to do:

```
$paragraphs = preg_split('/$\R?^:/m', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

**(UPDATED AGAIN - this will cover the 2 type of line breaks - \n or \r\n)**

This should then contain an array of non-empty strings representing your paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

You can split whole string into chunks using `"\n"` and just use first two  like below

```
$array = explode("\n", $data, 2);
echo $array[0] //paragraph 1
echo $array[1] //paragraph 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your content by carriage return "\n" using explode() function. This will give you an array of paragraphs. Then you will only need to display first two values in the array.

```
$contentArray = explode("\n", $content);
echo $contentArray[0] . $contentArray[1];
```

Please note that carriage return could differ from system to system. It could be "\n" or "\r\n".
You will need to test that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
substr($paragraph, 0, $nb_characters);
```

Comment: Would only work if you get the exact position of the 2nd occurrence of a carriage return to use as the $nb_characters parameter.